# Can't call method of OpenLayers object: 'getSource is not a function'

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 7.5.2 to create a simple map with one vector layer having two points. This works. I want to then access the layer object in the map and get to the point features to update their text attributes. However, I get "Uncaught TypeError: l.getSource is not a function" in the browser when I attempt to access the style objects, starting with getSource():

```
    let lyrs = map_obj.getAllLayers(); //works
    for (let l in lyrs) {
        source = l.getSource(); //doesn't work
        features = source.getFeaturesCollection(); //??
        for (let f in features) {
            alert('a feature');                 
        }
    }
```

Per the [ol documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html#getSource), the getSource method belongs to the layer object. This seems straight-forward so I'm at a loss. I'm new to OpenLayers.

Here's my [test page for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/tjm46uf7/).

Can you give me any pointers?

Comment: for ... in works on objects, not arrays, although `lyrs[l].getSource()` would work as it treats the array index as an object key.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @Mike - Ah, right! Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: If that has solved the problem, then post it as an answer to your own question (and accept the answer as correct).  Then everyone can see that this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In in my code sample, above, the syntax of `l.getSource()` is incorrect. Here's an updated code sample with corrected syntax.

```
let lyrs = map_obj.getAllLayers(); 
for (let l in lyrs) {
    source = lyrs[l].getSource();           
    let features = source.getFeaturesCollection();          
    features.forEach( function (feat, index) {  
        alert(index);                           
    });         
}
```